# DataGridView checkbox isn't showing checked on first item

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with four columns.  If the checkbox in the top left box is set to true, when the datagridview is displayed, it shows up unchecked until I move the mouse somewhere else or use an arrow key. How do I get it to show up checked?  I've tried "refresh" and "clearSelection" on my DataGridView, but neither works.

DatagridView columns: Primary key (hidden), Add to BOM (check box), Part # to be added (default string), Part already added (default string)

```
Enum ColumnID
     PK_PartNumber
     chkAddToBOM
     PartNotInBOM
     PartInBOM
End Enum

' Test code
For x = 1 To 3
    Dim R = dgv_E2Parts.Rows(dgv_E2Parts.Rows.Add)
    R.Cells(ColumnID.PK_PartNumber).Value = x
    R.Cells(ColumnID.chkAddToBOM).Value = True
    R.Cells(ColumnID.PartInBOM).Value = "ABC-" & x
Next
```

[image: Top left checkbox cell is set to true, shows unchecked until moved]

Top left checkbox cell is set to true, shows unchecked until the arrow or mouse movement

Comment: RefreshEdit fixes it, but Refresh doesn't.

Comment: The contents of that loop is silly. Don't add a row, get its index, get the row at that index and then set the value of each cell. Just add the row with the values, i.e. `dgv_E2Parts.Rows.Add(New Object() {x, True, "ABC-" & x})`. I'm not 100% sure that that will address your issue but I suspect that it will, because you're not changing the `Value` of any cells from the initial value the row was created with.

Comment: I'm afraid the real problem is more complex than an NewObject will allow.  For example, I have
   GetBatchedValue_ABC(Primary_Key,
       sub(Result)R.cells(ColumnID.xx).value=result)

And outside of the loop I have RunBatch_GetABC, which piles all the primary keys into one SQL statement to avoid N+1 problems.

Comment: As far as I can read what you just wrote, I don't see how that's an impediment to my suggestion. Are you saying that you don't know what all the cell values are before you add the row but you do immediately after adding it?

Comment: Actually, in this one, I'm not using callbacks, but most of my grids do.  And I feel that enumerated columns is cleaner vs relying on the order.

Comment: Just tested it, and adding new rows the way you mentioned doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I suspect that what's happening is that, as soon as you add that first row, it is the current row and the check box cell is the current cell and it is immediately in edit mode, so it doesn't reflect the change you make in code. My suggestion works because you are now adding the row with the value you want in that cell from the start, so there's no change to reflect. Another solution would likely be to change the edit mode for the grid (maybe only temporarily) so that that cell doesn't enter edit mode simply by being the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be assuming you got the code working right, and the first checkbox indeed is checked when debugging, if that's the problem you just need to shift focus to outside the datagridview since i encountered this problem recently as well.
Use this `ActiveControl = *any control except the gridview`